# org.springframework.jms.IllegalStateException: The Session is closed

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am using Apache Camel and ActiveMQ in my spring boot application. Sometimes it starts throwing an error that session is closed. I have to restart the application to get rid of this error.

I have gone through some articles which suggest that application is exhausting the max session limit(default 500). Next time when this error will occur I will look into the activemq panel to see active sessions corresponding to a connection.

Here is my configuration file:

```
<camelContext id="camelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <contextScan/>
    </camelContext>

    <bean class="xy.acb.task.TaskServiceBean">
        <property name="camelContext" ref="camelContext"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent" destroy-method="shutdown">
        <property name="autoStartup" value="true"/>
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <bean class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactoryBean">
                <property name="connectionFactory">
                    <bean class="org.apache.activemq.spring.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
                        <property name="brokerURL"
                                  value="${activemq.brokerURL:tcp://activemq:61616?daemon=true}"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
            <property name="acknowledgementModeName" value="CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE"/>
        <property name="deliveryMode" value="1"/>
        <property name="timeToLive" value="1260000"/>
    </bean>
```

Below is the error trace:

```
The Session is closed; nested exception is javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The Session is closed
        ; nested exception is javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The Session is closed
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:279)
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:169)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:496)
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.send(JmsConfiguration.java:228)
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.doSend(JmsProducer.java:431)
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.processInOnly(JmsProducer.java:385)
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.process(JmsProducer.java:153)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:120)
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:416)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
        at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:51)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProducer.process(UnitOfWorkProducer.java:74)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$2.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:375)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$2.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:343)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:233)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:343)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:168)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:119)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:105)
```

Answer (score 0):

From Activemq 5.7, maximumActive=500(default), is replaced with maximumActiveSessionPerConnection property. Default connections is 8. so totally 500 * 8  = 4000 sessions are allowed. Check which Activemq version you are using and then set the right properties you need to make it work.

Comment: I found that we were sending a huge number of requests to MongoDB via a crone and it was the time when we were facing "Session is closed" issue. We fixed the cron and now it is working fine.